# サーバーなしでPWA(Progressive Web Application)的なことをする

Tags: javascript, html

PWAをサーバーなしでダウンロードすることはできますか?
PWAを利用する場合、最初はHTTPSサーバーからダウンロードする必要がありますが、
これをHTTPSサーバーなしで、ローカル(file://)においてあるhtmlファイル上で行うことは可能なのでしょうか?

例えば、20問ぐらいのクイズを出題するhtmlファイル(jsとcssも含む)があるとします。(クイズの問題はhtmlに直に書いてある)
何問か解いた後、途中で中断し、その後、再度同じhtmlファイルを開くと、前回中断したところから再開されるようにしたいです。

この環境では非常に残念ですが、サーバーは使えず、WebExtensionのインストールもできません。

htmlとjsだけでこのようなことは可能でしょうか?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「前回中断したところから再開されるようにしたい」ということと`PWA`は関係のない話です。`PWA`が提供する主な機能はキャシュとプッシュ通知で、`PWA`を導入しても、「前回中断したところから再開されるようにしたい」ということはできません。

「前回中断したところから再開されるようにしたい」のであれば、`Web Storage`を使用して、適当なタイミングで現在開いているページを保存します。`localStorage`を使うのであれば次のように書きます。

```
localStorage.setItem('page', pagenumber);
```

再度開く時に、`localStorage`からそのページを取得して、そのページに移動すればいいだけです。

```
var page = localStorage.getItem('page');
```

`file://`の場合`json`からデータを読み込むようにしていると`Cross origin`でエラーになるのですが、htmlに直に書いてあるということなので動作します。また、`localStorage`は、`file://`の場合にも動きます。